# How to disable warning messages?

Tags: notifications, airplane-mode

On Android 4.3 un-rooted, is there a way to disable all the annoying warning messages that pop up when you enable Airplane Mode / disable Airplane Mode / raise the volume too high / etc?

Apparently [the Xposed mod allows to do this tweaking](http://www.droidforums.net/threads/disabling-warning-messages.246563/) but I have found no solution so far for an Android device that hasn't been rooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tasker with the AutoInput plugin to detect the pop ups and close them.

Or you can use Tasker to turn Wi-Fi, GPS etc on/off. You may have to add Tasker as an admin app for it to control the GPS and some other functions.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. You simply speculated that Tasker and AutoInput can do the  job but you do not confirm that it can. (Note that both the apps are equipped with lots of functions so nothing seems straightforward here). The only confirmation that can be given (IMO) is by providing the detailed steps. Please give us those steps, else, consider moving this answer into a comment.

Comment: I confirm it can. I use it. But both apps have lots of details, and Tasker in particular has a lengthy guide. The user must consult the guide. It's too lengthy to put here.

Comment: You're making an excuse. Simply mention the steps needed to make profile , the tasks and the actions needed to achieve the goal. See my answers for example http://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a96277%20tasker

Comment: Install the plugin, add a profile to Tasker with the plugin, configure the plugin with the name of the window/pop-up, configure an action for that pop-up to close that pop-up by having the plugin press the "Close" button, or "Yes" button, or whatever button you would normally press to close it. Each case is different and so will be the exact steps.

Comment: Please, see [answer]. Alternatively, see the most voted answers here and learn how to write good and detailed answers. Also, take the [tour] of this site. Carefully notice the line "*we're working together to build a **library of detailed answers***" -- my question, do you think that your answer comes even close to be considered a good quality, let alone a detailed one? Please [edit] once you're done with the links. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for sharing Mickets. It's very helpful for me. You have my vote up :)